# ImageReader callback is not working in android camera2 api?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

So, I wanted to grab a frame from the preview as soon as the autofocus is locked while the preview is in session without blocking the preview. Now, I dont get any error, however when I did a step wise debugging of my code, I noticed that my code escapes out of the imagereader callback. Hence, it doesnt save any image. I am building my code on top of Google's Sample Camera2 Code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the output image reader too late, and at such point it will never receive any image, even if you are seeing a preview.

All output surfaces must be created before the calling **createCaptureSession**, which means you need to create the **ImageReader** and configure it before the camera session starts, and to ensure the ImageReader's ‘**surface**’ is part of the output surfaces passed into the session when this one gets created.

Please check the next Google Sample for a working implementation of the camera2 API:

[Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java)